# How to use webdrivercss?

Tags: webdriver

```
graphicsmagick install is ok,
$ npm install webdrivercss is ok,
$ npm install webdriverio is ok,
```

And have a test.js,but don't konw to run test.js? Any help? thanks

Comment: Which test framework are you using? Mocha? Cucumber?

Comment: only installed graphicsmagick,webdrivercss,webdriverio,and don't know Which test framework,webdrivercss is not test framework? tks

Comment: webdrivercss is more of a plugin to webdriverio. Webdriverio has a test runner you may want to look at: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/gettingstarted.html. Or you may want to look into using Mocha to run your tests